# Multiple Django FusionCharts on same page

Tags: python, django, fusioncharts

I am trying to do the same as in this post [Multiple FusionCharts on Same page with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51586150/multiple-fusioncharts-on-same-page-with-django) and as far as I can see I am using the same approach as in the answer but it is not working. I have also tried putting the charts in a table as in the answer but only get chart1 again.

I also can't get chart2 or chart3 to appear on it's own, or get multiple copies of chart1 to appear. The code posted below gives chart1 but blank spaces (reserved space but no chart) for chart2 and chart3.

Using Django 2.0.4, Python 3.6.3, SQLite built in to Django and the Django dev server.

If anyone can spot what I am doing wrong I'd be very grateful.

**views.py (extract)**

```
def charts(request):
'''Various Temperature Charts'''

#### TEMPERATURES TODAY CHART ##### CHART1
# DATA SERIES
lastdayevent = Event.objects.filter(reading='AMB', location = 'Hall').order_by('-date')[0] # get event from latest day
querydate = lastdayevent.date # Use last day with data rather than today. Allows testing with old database files. 
qsH= Event.objects.filter( reading ='AMB',  location = 'Hall', date = querydate).order_by('-time')
qsM= Event.objects.filter( reading ='AMB',  location = 'Bed_Mstr',date = querydate).order_by('-time')
qsE= Event.objects.filter( reading ='EXT_TEMP',  location = 'Bed_Mstr',date = querydate).order_by('-time')

datalist_hall = hourly_average_list(qsH)
datalist_bed = hourly_average_list(qsM)
datalist_ext = hourly_average_list(qsE)

series_hall = charts_getseries(datalist_hall, 'Hall')
series_bed = charts_getseries(datalist_bed, 'Master Bedroom')
series_ext = charts_getseries(datalist_ext, 'Outside')

# CHART SETUP 
# Chart data is passed to the `dataSource` parameter, as dict, in the form of key-value pairs.
dataSource1 = {}
dataSource1['chart'] = {
    "caption": "Temperatures Today",
    "subCaption": str(querydate),
    "xAxisName": "Hour",
    "yAxisName": "Temp C",
    #"lineThickness": "2",
    #"numberPrefix": "",
    "theme": "zune",
    "showValues": "0",
    "rotateLabels": "0",
    "setAdaptiveYMin": "1",
    }

# categories (x axis)dataSource1['categories'] = []
catlist = []
for i in range (24):
    catlist.append({'label':str(i)})
dataSource1['categories'] = []
dataSource1['categories'].append({'category':catlist})  

# add data series 
dataSource1['dataset'] = []
dataSource1['dataset'].append(series_hall)
dataSource1['dataset'].append(series_bed)
dataSource1['dataset'].append(series_ext)

# Create an object for the 2D line chart using the FusionCharts class constructor   
# parameters are: chart type, id, width, height, render at (html id in template), data format, datasource file              
chart1 = FusionCharts("msline", "ex1" , "600", "450", "chart-1", "json", dataSource1)

####### 28 DAY TEMPS ##### CHART2, CHART3
# DATA SERIES - day and night
dusk = 68400 # 19:00 in seconds since midnight
dawn = 25200 # 07:00 in seconds since midnight
search_period = datetime.timedelta(days=28)
lastdayevent = Event.objects.filter(reading='AMB', location = 'Hall').order_by('-date')[0] # get event from latest day
querydate = lastdayevent.date - search_period # Use last day with data rather than today. Allows testing with old database files. 
qsPeriod= Event.objects.filter(date__gte = querydate)
qsDay= qsPeriod.filter(time__range = (dawn, dusk))
qsNight= qsPeriod.exclude(time__range = (dawn, dusk))

# catlist is returned by daily_average_list, therefore have to overwite each time daily_average_list called
# catlist is created from qsDay (or night) as Hall, Ext, Master may have different days missing. 
# daily_averages works on whole date set and adds "none" values for missing days. Keeps all series aligned
datalist_day_hall, catlist = daily_average_list(qsDay, 'HALL', 'AMB')
datalist_day_bed, catlist = daily_average_list(qsDay, 'Bed_Mstr', 'AMB')
datalist_day_ext, catlist = daily_average_list(qsDay, 'Bed_Mstr','EXT_TEMP' )

series_day_hall = charts_getseries(datalist_day_hall, 'Hall')
series_day_bed = charts_getseries(datalist_day_bed, 'Master Bedroom')
series_day_ext = charts_getseries(datalist_day_ext, 'Outside')

datalist_night_hall, catlist = daily_average_list(qsNight, 'HALL', 'AMB')
datalist_night_bed, catlist = daily_average_list(qsNight, 'Bed_Mstr', 'AMB')
datalist_night_ext, catlist = daily_average_list(qsNight, 'Bed_Mstr','EXT_TEMP' )

series_night_hall = charts_getseries(datalist_night_hall, 'Hall')
series_night_bed = charts_getseries(datalist_night_bed, 'Master Bedroom')
series_night_ext = charts_getseries(datalist_night_ext, 'Outside')

# Chart Setup chart 2 daytime
# Chart data is passed to the `dataSource` parameter, as dict, in the form of key-value pairs.
dataSource2 = {}
dataSource2['chart'] = {
    "caption": "Daytime Temps Last 28 Days",
    "subCaption": str(querydate),
    "xAxisName": "Date",
    "yAxisName": "Temp C",
    #"lineThickness": "2",
    #"numberPrefix": "",
    "theme": "zune",
    "showValues": "0",
    "rotateLabels": "0",
    "setAdaptiveYMin": "1",
    }

# categories (x axis)dataSource1['categories'] = []
dataSource2['categories'] = []
dataSource2['categories'].append({'category':catlist})  

# add data series 
dataSource2['dataset'] = []
dataSource2['dataset'].append(series_day_hall)
dataSource2['dataset'].append(series_day_bed)
dataSource2['dataset'].append(series_day_ext)

# Create an object for the 2D line chart using the FusionCharts class constructor                   
chart2 = FusionCharts("msline", "ex2" , "600", "450", "chart-2", "json", dataSource2)

# Chart Setup chart 3 nighttime
# Chart data is passed to the `dataSource` parameter, as dict, in the form of key-value pairs.
dataSource3 = {}
dataSource3['chart'] = {
    "caption": "Nighttime Temps Last 28 Days",
    "subCaption": str(querydate),
    "xAxisName": "Date",
    "yAxisName": "Temp C",
    #"lineThickness": "2",
    #"numberPrefix": "",
    "theme": "zune",
    "showValues": "0",
    "rotateLabels": "0",
    "setAdaptiveYMin": "1",
    }

# categories (x axis)dataSource1['categories'] = []
dataSource3['categories'] = []
dataSource3['categories'].append({'category':catlist})  

# add data series 
dataSource3['dataset'] = []
dataSource3['dataset'].append(series_night_hall)
dataSource3['dataset'].append(series_night_bed)
dataSource3['dataset'].append(series_night_ext)

# Create an object for the 2D line chart using the FusionCharts class constructor                   
chart3 = FusionCharts("msline", "ex3" , "600", "450", "chart-3", "json", dataSource3)

# BUILD TEMPLATE CONTEXT
context_dict = {'output1':chart1.render(),
                'output2':chart2.render(), 
                'output3':chart3.render(),                    
               }

return render(request, 'hsrvr/charts.html', context_dict)
```

**template** charts.html

```
{% extends "hsrvr/main.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}Charts{% endblock %}
{% block addscripts %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js" %}"></script> 
{% endblock %}
{% block pagename %}Charts{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>This page shows how the temperatures around the house have moved today.</p> 
<h1>Temperature Movements Today</h1>
<div id="chart-1">{{ output1|safe }}</div>

<h1>28 Day Average Daytime Temperature</h1>
<p>This chart shows the daily average daytime (7am - 7pm) external and bedroom temperatures for the last 28 days.</p>
<div id="chart-2">{{ output2|safe }}</div>
<h1>28 Day Average Nighttime Temperature</h1>
<p>This chart shows the daily average nighttime (7pm - 7am) external and bedroom temperatures for the last 28 days.</p>
<div id="chart-3">{{ output3|safe }}</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The dataSource1 object is;

> {'chart': {'caption': 'Temperatures Today', 'subCaption':
>   '2018-08-16', 'xAxisName': 'Hour', 'yAxisName': 'Temp C', 'theme':
>   'zune', 'showValues': '0', 'rotateLabels': '0', 'setAdaptiveYMin':
>   '1'}, 'categories': [{'category': [{'label': '0'}, {'label': '1'},
>   {'label': '2'}, {'label': '3'}, {'label': '4'}, {'label': '5'},
>   {'label': '6'}, {'label': '7'}, {'label': '8'}, {'label': '9'},
>   {'label': '10'}, {'label': '11'}, {'label': '12'}, {'label': '13'},
>   {'label': '14'}, {'label': '15'}, {'label': '16'}, {'label': '17'},
>   {'label': '18'}, {'label': '19'}, {'label': '20'}, {'label': '21'},
>   {'label': '22'}, {'label': '23'}]}], 'dataset': [{'seriesname':
>   'Hall', 'data': [{'value': '22.56'}, {'value': '22.50'}, {'value':
>   '22.50'}, {'value': '22.50'}, {'value': '22.46'}, {'value': '22.43'},
>   {'value': '22.44'}, {'value': '22.48'}, {'value': '22.59'}, {'value':
>   '22.69'}, {'value': '22.80'}, {'value': '22.71'}, {'value': '22.75'},
>   {'value': '22.75'}, {'value': '22.75'}, {'value': '22.60'}, {'value':
>   '22.50'}, {'value': '22.78'}, {'value': '22.86'}, {'value': '22.83'},
>   {'value': '22.78'}, {'value': 'None'}, {'value': 'None'}, {'value':
>   'None'}]}, {'seriesname': 'Master Bedroom', 'data': [{'value':
>   '24.01'}, {'value': '24.18'}, {'value': '24.30'}, {'value': '24.34'},
>   {'value': '24.37'}, {'value': '24.43'}, {'value': '24.43'}, {'value':
>   '24.01'}, {'value': '23.43'}, {'value': '23.68'}, {'value': '23.66'},
>   {'value': '23.62'}, {'value': '23.62'}, {'value': '23.78'}, {'value':
>   '23.81'}, {'value': '23.87'}, {'value': '23.93'}, {'value': '23.89'},
>   {'value': '23.89'}, {'value': '23.89'}, {'value': '23.83'}, {'value':
>   'None'}, {'value': 'None'}, {'value': 'None'}]}, {'seriesname':
>   'Outside', 'data': [{'value': '18.67'}, {'value': '18.29'}, {'value':
>   '17.95'}, {'value': '18.14'}, {'value': '18.06'}, {'value': '18.05'},
>   {'value': '17.93'}, {'value': '18.39'}, {'value': '17.68'}, {'value':
>   '18.00'}, {'value': '17.53'}, {'value': '17.50'}, {'value': '16.96'},
>   {'value': '15.61'}, {'value': '16.51'}, {'value': '18.28'}, {'value':
>   '18.87'}, {'value': '19.45'}, {'value': '18.97'}, {'value': '18.23'},
>   {'value': '17.25'}, {'value': 'None'}, {'value': 'None'}, {'value':
>   'None'}]}]}

and dataSource2 is;

> {'chart': {'caption': 'Daytime Temps Last 28 Days', 'subCaption':
>   '2018-07-19', 'xAxisName': 'Date', 'yAxisName': 'Temp C', 'theme':
>   'zune', 'showValues': '0', 'rotateLabels': '0', 'setAdaptiveYMin':
>   '1'}, 'categories': [{'category': [20180719, 20180720, 20180724,
>   20180804, 20180805, 20180806, 20180807, 20180808, 20180809, 20180810,
>   20180811, 20180812, 20180813, 20180814, 20180815, 20180816]}],
>   'dataset': [{'seriesname': 'Hall', 'data': [{'value': 'None'},
>   {'value': 'None'}, {'value': 'None'}, {'value': 'None'}, {'value':
>   'None'}, {'value': 'None'}, {'value': 'None'}, {'value': 'None'},
>   {'value': 'None'}, {'value': 'None'}, {'value': 'None'}, {'value':
>   'None'}, {'value': 'None'}, {'value': 'None'}, {'value': 'None'},
>   {'value': 'None'}, {'value': 'None'}]}, {'seriesname': 'Master
>   Bedroom', 'data': [{'value': 'None'}, {'value': 'None'}, {'value':
>   'None'}, {'value': 'None'}, {'value': '27.42'}, {'value': '26.91'},
>   {'value': '26.70'}, {'value': '104.87'}, {'value': '33.41'}, {'value':
>   '80.42'}, {'value': '22.88'}, {'value': '22.62'}, {'value': '22.95'},
>   {'value': '22.62'}, {'value': '23.35'}, {'value': '23.76'}, {'value':
>   '23.77'}]}, {'seriesname': 'Outside', 'data': [{'value': 'None'},
>   {'value': 'None'}, {'value': 'None'}, {'value': 'None'}, {'value':
>   '29.05'}, {'value': '28.59'}, {'value': '30.73'}, {'value': '104.23'},
>   {'value': '35.21'}, {'value': '78.80'}, {'value': '18.05'}, {'value':
>   '22.24'}, {'value': '19.99'}, {'value': '22.15'}, {'value': '23.29'},
>   {'value': '23.20'}, {'value': '17.81'}]}]}

There are some "none" values in there because my raspberry pi temperature sensors kept falling over but there is enough data in each chart to produce some sort of plot. The very high temps are caused by a default sensor error reading of 120 C (when the DS18b20 sensor fell over but the pi didn't) which inflates some of the daily average temps.

Looking at the rendered web page, the charts are created in a

```
<span style><svg><div style></span>
```

pattern, but for chart2 and chart3 the svg element is missing.

This is an edited extract from the rendered page

```
<main>

<p>This page shows how the temperatures around the house have moved today.</p> 
<h1>Temperature Movements Today</h1>
<div id="chart-1"><span id="ex1" class="fusioncharts-container" style="position: relative; text-align: left; line-height: normal; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: normal; font-variant: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: none; direction: ltr; width: 600px; height: 450px;"><svg height="450" version="1.1" width="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style=#EDITED#</svg><div style="position: absolute; z-index: 50; top: 0px; right: auto; left: auto; overflow: hidden; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100); box-shadow: rgb(153, 153, 153) 2px 2px 5px; padding: 5px 3px; display: none;"></div></span></div>

<h1>28 Day Average Daytime Temperature</h1>
<p>This chart shows the daily average daytime (7am - 7pm) external and bedroom temperatures for the last 28 days.</p>
<div id="chart-2"><span id="ex2" class="fusioncharts-container" style="position: relative; text-align: left; line-height: normal; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: normal; font-variant: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: none; direction: ltr; width: 600px; height: 450px;"><div style="position: absolute; z-index: 50; top: 0px; right: auto; left: auto; overflow: hidden; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100); box-shadow: rgb(153, 153, 153) 2px 2px 5px; padding: 5px 3px; display: none;"></div></span></div>
<h1>28 Day Average Nighttime Temperature</h1>
<p>This chart shows the daily average nighttime (7pm - 7am) external and bedroom temperatures for the last 28 days.</p>
<div id="chart-3"><span id="ex3" class="fusioncharts-container" style="position: relative; text-align: left; line-height: normal; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: normal; font-variant: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: none; direction: ltr; width: 600px; height: 450px;"><div style="position: absolute; z-index: 50; top: 0px; right: auto; left: auto; overflow: hidden; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100); box-shadow: rgb(153, 153, 153) 2px 2px 5px; padding: 5px 3px; display: none;"></div></span></div>

</main>
```

Comment: You might get an answer fastr (or at all) if you only post the relevant data (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example remove all styles and only show a small subset of your data sources, as long you can still reproduce your error.

Comment: Pinkie Swirl, many thanks for your comment - you solved the problem! As I wasn't sure where the problem was I included everything I thought was relevant. I went through again to edit it down as you suggested and the answer was staring me in the face - I just couldn't see it before. Turns out the categories 'catlist' created by a support method not posted was not putting the 'label' key in the dict. Now fixed. Thanks again.